# Discord 'on_member_join' function not working

Tags: python, discord.py

My on_member_join doesnt seem to work. I wanted my bot to say out the names of the members that joined the sever but it doesnt detect if someone has joined or left.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready ")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member.name} has joined this server')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member}was removed')

client.run('*************************')
```

It is printing "bot is ready" on the terminal so the bot is working. But isn't detecting members leaving or joining pls help.

Comment: The bot has to be in the server, to detect new people joining. Already joined people arent detected.

Comment: @Deru it is already in a server  n I have tried removing my second account n adding it back in but still it doesn't print that on the terminal

Comment: Also no errors?

Comment: @Deru nope no errors

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using discord python 1.5.0 or above, it's a common error, you just need [Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).
If there's a error, you are supposed to read it, it will redirect you to your bot in the discord dev portal, there you can activate the privileged gateway intents [check this out](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents)

And add this to your code

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)
```

Answer (score -3):

i solved this problem to downgrade discord.py

maybe intents option is error.

i'm already using discord api forum intents option but not working

so if u wanna on_member_join and remove events, downgrade your discord.py under version 1.5.0

u type this in console

```
pip install discord.py==1.4.2
```

and in your cords remove all about intents cord and activate your cords

that's it.

Comment: You're not supposed to downgrade your Discord, that will make it break in the future & force OP to use the proper solution anyways. Instead of downgrading his Discord he just has to pass in intents which are required in the new version. Avoiding intents by downgrading just means he has to upgrade again & use intents in a few months when intents become required.

Comment: i had to do finish my project in university. so i cant avoid downgrade about 'discord version' because that function not working then i can't finish my project. That's why I just told, how to solve it. and i send e-mail to discord co, my problem. i'm waiting answer. i want to some good news from discord co.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. If you just upgrade your discord & pass in the intents then it'll also work & you'll be able to finish your project.

Comment: i don't get what you mean either. in newest discord.py version intents is not working ^O^

Comment: @user14605071 make sure to add `intents=intents` on your commands.Bot(), Example client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix", intents=intents`, Downgrading is not a good option.