# Python does not detect "on_member_join"

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
Bot = discord.Client()
token = open('token.txt', 'r').read()
@Bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member} has joined the server")

client.run(token)
```

"on_message" works properly but "on_member_join" does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord 'on\_member\_join' function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348389/discord-on-member-join-function-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events related to members will require the special `member intents`  to be enabled in the developer portal as well as defined in your code.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Prefix', intents=intents)
```