# My bot's discord.py welcomer and leave message is not working?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

This is my code I pretty much used everything needed this is still not working.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   await client.get_channel(857514680562221066).send(f"{member.name} has joined The Fasn Freinds Hub")
   await member.send('Welcome to The Fasn Friends Hub, Remember to drop you real name in the general chat, Have a good day.')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
   await client.get_channel(857515876815339520).send(f"{member.name} has left")
   await member.send('You left The Fasn Friends Hub, Hope you had a great time.')
```

I don't know the problem and neither there is any error, I still don't know what is messing up. Also my intents are on.

Comment: Did you setup intents?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord 'on\_member\_join' function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348389/discord-on-member-join-function-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Well basically may the problem from your intents in your bot. First you need to active it from the Discord Developer Portal in your bot dashboard and than using it in your `client` variable like

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(prefix, intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member:discord.Member):
# Your code


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member:discord.Member):
# Your code

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try creating a dm channel with that user before sending the message like:

**Member Join**

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  channel = await client.fetch_channel(857514680562221066)
  await channel.send(f"{member.name} has joined The Fasn Freinds Hub")
  await member.create_dm()
 try:
  await member.dm_channel.send('Welcome to The Fasn Friends Hub, Remember to drop you real name in the general chat, Have a good day.')
 except discord.HTTPException:
  pass
```

**Member Leave**

```py
@client.event    
async def on_member_remove(member):
  channel = await client.fetch_channel(857514680562221066)
  await channel.send(f"{member.name} has left")
```

I am a beginner at discord.py too and so im not sure if it will work

EDIT AFTER TESTING : I forgot that if the bot has to send a private message to user, it must be in a mutual guild with that user so I don't know a way to send message once the user leaves the server

Comment: btw also, if not already done, enable the intents as well `intents = discord.Intents().all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'yourprefix', intents=intents)`

Comment: Creating a dm channel changes nothing. discord.py creates one if there isn't already one. although the intents is most likely the issue

Comment: Well done everything with the prefixs and intents

Comment: @AarshRaghuvanshi you can try changing `get_user` to `fetch_user`. I tried it in my code and it worked